# Geometric proof that a Pythagorean triple has a number divisible by $3$?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, pythagorean-triples

Can I infer from

“If $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(a,3)=(b,3)=1$ then $a^2+b^2\neq c^2$ for any $c\in\mathbb{N}$”

that any pythagorean triple has a number which is divisible by $3$?

If so, how can this relationship be proved geometrically?

Comment: if a right triangle has integer length sides, then the length of at least one of its legs is divisible by $3$

Comment: I meant... can it be proved geometrically? Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can infer that.  As for proving geometrically.  Not sure.  It'd be a pain.  Goemetric algebra is always hard.

Comment: What does (a, 3) mean?  Is (a, 3) just a pair of 'a' and '3', or is there more to it?

Comment: $(a,3)$ is short for $\gcd(a,3)$

Comment: The inference you ask for is completely straight forward. The only thing you need to check is that being coprime to 3 is equivalent to not being divisible by 3. This is indeed true, and follows from the fact that 3 is prime.

Comment: However when you say can it be proved geometrically the 'it' probably does not refer to the inference but to the statement in quotes itself?

Comment: This is a nice challenge and I will think about it. In the mean time, here is an algebraic proof. There are 2 types of integers not divisible by 3: those that are 1 mod 3 and those that are 2 mod 3. For the pair $a, b$ there are hence 4 possibilities and you can quite easily check that the relationship holds in all 4 cases.

Comment: Yes, “it” refers to the statement in quotes.

Comment: well if we create linear units of $3$ "bits" and square units of $9$ "bits" we ca probably manipulate an figure that boils down to a square with an area of bits that we can prove is not a perfect square integer.  .... I don't really want to try.

Comment: It's also true that every Pythagorean triple has a number divisible by $4$ and a number divisible by $5$ (these could be the same number like in $20, 21, 29$)

Comment: To paraphrase @Ned   If neither $a$ nor $b$ are divisible by $3$, you do not have a Pythagorean triple because $60$ always divides the product of $A,B,C$.

Comment: I'd be intrigued if one could make a geometric argument.  I imagine it'd be futzy but it'd be interesting.

Comment: Geometry seems inappropriate for a divisibility proof. Line segments are trisectable regardless of the ratio of their length to a "unit" line segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple graphical solution to the problem.**

Red region: Has unit squares divisible by 3.

Green region: All unit squares together are a multiple of 3.

Yellow squares: Left out square(s).

[image]

If you have two squares of type 1, you will have 2 yellow squares, which don't fit into any type of square.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail? Feel free to use $a,b$ and $c$ as in the question.

Comment: You have two squares of side a and b. There are only 3 general types of squares as shown in the diagram (3 remainders : side leaving remainder 1, 2 or 0 on division by 3 ). Now, you say that both the given square (a^2 & b^2) are of type 1 and their sum (a^2 + b^2) is another square (c^2) ? Well, then the resultant square (c^2) must have 2 yellow unit squares which is not present in any of 3 general types of square. So, it is not possible.

Comment: In diagram, each side is of the form 3k + r where k is any arbitrary non-negative integer and r can take a value from the set{1, 2, 0}. Then, the colors show how we can group them in multiples of 3.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly detailed(irrelevant) approach:
If any of, m, n are divisible by 3, then we are done as $\ (a,b,c)=({ m }^{ 2 }-{ n }^{ 2 },\quad 2mn,\quad { m }^{ 2 }+{ n }^{ 2 }) $ and $\ 3|b $. Hence, assume both m and n aren't multiples of 3. Therefore $$\ m\equiv 1,2\quad (mod\quad3)\\ n\equiv 1,2\quad (mod\quad3)$$
This implies that $$\ { m }^{ 2 }\equiv { n }^{ 2 }\equiv 1(mod\quad 3) $$ Hence $$\ { m }^{ 2 }-{ n }^{ 2 }=a\equiv 0(mod\quad 3)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out! I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive solution of Pythagorean triple is given below.

$(a,b,c)=(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$.

Assuming $gcd(a,b)=1$, then $ab = 2mn(m^2-n^2) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$  (Fermat's little theorem)

Hence  $a$ or $b$ is divisible by $3$.

Thus, if $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then $a$ or $b$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: If $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then $a$ or $b$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

If in the Pythagorean triangle $(a,b,c),$ where $c$ is the hypotenuse, we have
$c=3m\pm1$  and $a=3n\pm1,$ then $$(3\,|\, (c^2-1)) \text{ and } (3\,|\, (a^2-1))\Rightarrow 3\,|\,(c^2-a^2)\Rightarrow 3\,|\,b^2\Rightarrow 3\,|\,b.$$

Geometrically.

If in the Pythagorean triangle the hypotenuse and leg do not divide to $3$, then the squares difference divides to $3$.

[image: The squares difference]

Comment: Why should $c=3m\pm1$?

Comment: @WolfgangKais Because it belongs to Pythagorean triple.

Comment: How can this be a reason, even for a non-geometrical proof? Of course, we both know that it is true, and It follows from $3\nmid c$, but this has to be shown first. Otherwise, we also could accept "$3 \mid a \lor 3 \mid b$ because $a$ and $b$ are the legs of a Pythagorean triple" as a proof.